# Finding unlinked data in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have three tables like this:

```
Person table: primary - PersonKey
PersonFieldValue table: contains a PersonKey and a PersonFieldKey
PersonField table: primary - PersonFieldKey.
```

This also contains a Description field and two bit fields called IsRequired and IsLateRequirement

I have been pulling my hair out to come up with a query that will give me a list of people that do not have a record in the PersonFieldValue table that matches records from the PersonField table where one of the two bit fields are true along with the description of the field that is missing. So, given this data:

Person

```
PersonKey
    1
    2
```

PersonField

```
PersonFieldKey    Description     IsRequired     IsLateRequirement
    1             Thing1              1                 0
    2             Thing2              0                 1
    3             Thing3              1                 0
    4             Thing4              0                 0
```

PersonFieldValue

```
PersonKey         PersonFieldKey
    1                   3
    1                   4
    2                   1
    2                   2
```

I should get this data:

```
PersonKey         MissingFieldDescription
    1             Thing1
    1             Thing2
    2             Thing3
```

Notice how only the PersonField records that either have IsRequired or IsLateRequirement set to 1 are checked to see if they are missing.

So, how do I do this?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.PersonKey, pf.Description as 'MissingFieldDescription' 
 FROM Person p, PersonField pf
  WHERE pf.PersonFieldKey NOT IN 
  (select PersonFieldKey FROM PersonFieldValue WHERE PersonKey = p.PersonKey)
  AND (pf.IsRequired = 1 or pf.IsLateRequirement = 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  This shows everything that matches.  Not everything that doesn't.  I am trying to find the person records that have no matching PersonFieldValue records for PersonFields that have one of the two bit fields set to true.  This gives me everything that matches where one of the bit fields is true.

Comment: Sorry @Brian, I misunderstood your initial requirement. Try the above edit - please test it thoroughly. If you'd like me to explain how it works let me know.

Comment: This is perfect.  I was able to modify it for other fields as well and is much shorter than the solution I had come up with (pivots and dynamic sql).  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Below query will do the job, i have tested it [Assuming its for oracle ]:

```
SELECT a.KEY,description FROM(
SELECT decode(personKey,1,2,personKey) KEY,personFieldKey
FROM PersonFieldValue
UNION
SELECT decode(personKey,2,1,personKey) KEY,personFieldKey
FROM PersonFieldValue) a, PersonField c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PersonFieldValue b
                   WHERE a.KEY=b.personkey 
                  AND a.personfieldkey = b.personfieldkey)
and (isRequired=1 OR isLateRequirement=1)
and c.personFieldKey=a.personFieldKey;
```

For those who want to test, can you following script to generate schema:

```
create table PersonFieldValue (personKey number, personFieldKey number);

create table perseon(personKey number);

create table personfield(personFieldKey number,description varchar2(100),isRequired number, isLateRequirement number);

insert into personField values(1,'thing1',1,0);
insert into personField values(2,'thing2',0,1);
insert into personField values(3,'thing3',1,0);
insert into personField values(4,'thing4',0,0);

insert into PersonFieldValue values(1,3);
insert into PersonFieldValue values(1,4);
insert into PersonFieldValue values(2,1);
insert into PersonFieldValue values(2,2);
```